# Вернуть строку с пробелами и заглавными буквами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нашел здесь аналогичную задачу, но, возможно, ввиду непредоставления полного условия задачи, лучший ответ был неправильным.

Все «заказы» выглядят сейчас примерно так: "milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza" Но они хотят получать заказ в виде красивой чистой строки с пробелами и прописными буквами, например: "Burger Fries Chick Pizza Pizza Pizza
Напиши функцию get_order, которая принимает строку order в качестве аргумента и возвращает строку с более четким порядком, с пробелами и прописными буквами.
Примечания:
Строка на выходе может содержать дубликаты, например "Chicken Pizza Pizza"
Персонал кухни ожидает, что блюда будут расположены в том же порядке, в каком они указаны в меню.
Пункты меню достаточно просты, пункт не может быть частью другого пункта

Вот такое решение пока придумал, но система не принимает, помогите пожалуйста.

```py
def get_order(order: str) -> str:
    menu = ("Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke")
    result = []
    for i in range(len(order)):
        if order[i:] in menu:
            result.append(order[i:].capitalize())
    return " ".join(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть решения - удалять слова из меню из заказа по очереди, считая количество выбывших букв, тем самым считая кол-во определенных блюд.

```
def get_order(order: str) -> str:
    menu = ("Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke")
    result, length = [], len(order)

    for item in menu:
        result += [item] * ((length - len(order.replace(item.lower(), ''))) // len(item))
    return " ".join(result)


print(get_order('milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza'))
```

```
Burger Fries Chicken Pizza Pizza Pizza Sandwich Milkshake Milkshake Coke
```

Comment: Браво. Кстати, нашли еще такое решение:                                                                                                
/ def get_order(order: str) -> str:  
/    menu = ("Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke")
/    result = []
/    for dish in menu:
/        if dish.lower() in order:
/            dish_quantity = order.count(dish.lower())
/            result.extend([dish] * dish_quantity)
/    return " ".join(result)

Comment: @Void Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.